# How to define a method within a class to create an object of the same class?

Tags: python, class, oop, methods

I have an issue I am stuck with. I am supposed to define a method that will create a new object in my class. My code is as below:

```
class Email:
    
    def __init__(self, has_been_read, email_contents, is_spam, from_address):
        # Asserting has_been_read & is_spam variables as booleans
        assert type(has_been_read) == bool and type(is_spam) == bool
        self.has_been_read = has_been_read
        self.email_contents = email_contents
        self.is_spam = is_spam
        self.from_address = from_address
        # Predefining booleans as False
        is_spam = False
        has_been_read = False
  
    def mark_as_read(self):
        # Creating method to change has_been_read boolean to True
        return self.has_been_read == True
    
    def mark_as_spam(self):
        # Creating method to change is_spam to True
        return self.is_spam == True
    
    inbox = []
    
    def add_email(self):
```

So what I would need to do is create a method called `add_email` which will take in the `email_contents` and `from_address` to create a new `Email` object, but for some reason I can't figure out how to define a method that would create an object? Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: `return Email(email_contents, from_address)`? inside `add_email`

Answer (score 0):

You can use return to do what you want. Check the following code:

```
def add_email(self, email_contents, from_address):
    return Email(False, email_contents, False, from_address)
```